# How to force light mode in react native expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I've tried `Appearance.set({ colorScheme: 'light' });` and `"userInterfaceStyle": "light"` but my app still forces white colors to black.

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to look at your configuration. Per the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/user-interface/color-themes/#configuration) in your app.json you should use:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light"
  }
}
```

and to validate there isn't an issue it raises that you should install [`expo-system-ui`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/system-ui/#installation)

and to validate wether there is an issue run the command:

```
npx expo config --type introspect
```

Comment: I installed expo-system-ui and ran the `npx expo config --type introspect`, but nothing has changed and introspect isn't showing any warns.

Comment: Then I would advise editing your question with maybe your app.json and further information because you do not give much to go off of and I can only answer based on what I know from learning off the docs.

Answer (score 0):

There is some android devices forces applications to dark mode even you change through your app.json.It may disrupt application UI.

I recommend using expo-config-plugins to disable forceDarkAllowed value.